# java grade to GPA

Tags: java, syntax-error

I have an java application which convert input grade A,B,C,D,E and F into GPA points, but I have error not sure where is mistakes was, also how i can improved the code below so that user not entering input other than grade?

```
    import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

  public class Program
 {
     public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

      String letterGrade = " ";
      double gradePoints;
      boolean error = true;

      System.out.println("Enter A Letter Grade: ");
      letterGrade = keyboard.next();

      if( letterGrade == "A+")
      {
          gradePoints = 4.0;
      }
      else if ( letterGrade == "A")
      {
          gradePoints = 4.0;
      }
      else if( letterGrade == "A-")
      {
          gradePoints = 3.67; 
      }
      else if ( letterGrade == "B+")
      {
          gradePoints = 3.33;
      }
      else if( letterGrade == "B")
      {
          gradePoints = 3.0; 
      }
      else if ( letterGrade == "B-")
      {
          gradePoints = 2.67;
      }
      else if( letterGrade == "C+")
      {
          gradePoints = 2.33; 
      }
      else if ( letterGrade == "C")
      {
          gradePoints = 2.0;
      }
      else if( letterGrade == "F")
      {
          gradePoints = 0.0; 
      }
      else(error)
      {
        System.out.println("Error, you did not enter the correct information");
      }
        if(!error)
        {
        System.out.println("Your grade point(GPA) is " + gradePoints);

        }




    }
 }
```

Comment: Double equals! :-) letterGrade.equals("A+"), sorry

Comment: Program.java:19: incompatible types
found   : java.lang.String
required: boolean
      if( letterGrade = "A+")
for all letters

Comment: replace = with == in your `if` statements

Comment: LOL. Everybody is behind the = versus == but nobody sees that they are objects!

Comment: And now you don't ever set error to false so you will never display the result ...

Comment: so what is wrong with above code..?

Answer (score 1):

you have to check string equality using equals() method

```
if(letterGrade = "A+")

to 

if(letterGrade.equals("A+"))
```

however, you are assigning "A+" to letterGrad not checking if letterGrad==A+

`=` is an assignment operator, `==` is equality operator (to check if two primitives have equal value, or two object references point to the same object). '.equals()' is a method from java.lang.Object() class which is used to check if two objects are equals.

Answer (score 1):

First

You don't compare Strings (or other objects) with `==`; you use the `equals` method. Comparing directly with `==` tells you if both objects are the same, not if their values are the same. In the case of Strings, in your program `equalsIgnoreCase` would be more appropiate.

Also, mind you that the comparation operator is `==`; `=` is the assignment operator and does not check for equality; `letter = "F"` puts in `letter` a new Object that holds `F`. Your error is due that the expression `letter = "F"` "returns" the value that is being assigned (an String holding "F").

Doing

```
if (letter = "F") {
```

means

```
letter <-- new String("F")
if ("F") <-- This does not compile because it expects a boolean (if (true)  or if(false)
```

About the input control, you can't do much apart of what you have done, otherwise you would need a GUI.

Answer (score 0):

check on this way

```
   else if( letterGrade.equalsIgnoreCase("A-"))
   {
      gradePoints = 3.7; 
   }
```

change in other places also

if you want to check user input is valid you can check it in this way

```
   String grades = "A+B+CDA-";

    if(grades.indexOf("A")==0){
        System.out.println("imhere");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First your `if` statement is wrong.

It should be `if( letterGrade == "A+")`.

Note that you should use `==` for comparison.

And if you want to compare two strings than java provides better way to do it that matches the contents of the string because `==` operator compares references and not contents.

`if(letterGrade.equals("A+"))`  or `if( "A+".equals(letterGrade))`

Both of them will return a boolean value (`true` if contents of letterGrade matches "A+" and `false` if not).